# Dual GPU xorg.conf ignores XScreen on one GPU and uses xrandr

Tags: x11, xorg

Dual GPU X11 using xorg to separate workloads and screens. 2 GPU 3 screens/monitors. Basically

GPU 0 => XScreen 0.0 => Monitor 0 (left)

GPU 1 => XScreen 0.1 => Monitor 1 (center)

GPU 0 => XScreen 0.2 => Monitor 2 (right)

When I set this up the system only acknowledges 2 XScreens (one per GPU) which then lumps the flanking screens together which breaks placements.

Any input on why this is happening would be appreaciated.

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "PootSlap"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    Screen      2  "Screen2" RightOf "Screen1"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    Option “Xinerama” “0”
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "ACR"
    ModelName      "Acer G246HYL"
    HorizSync       31.0 - 75.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "ACR"
    ModelName      "Acer SA270"
    HorizSync       31.0 - 84.0
    VertRefresh     48.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor2"
    VendorName     "ACR"
    ModelName      "Acer G247HYL"
    HorizSync       31.0 - 75.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "amdgpu"
    BusID       "PCI:48:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card1"
    Driver      "nvidia"
    BusID       "PCI:16:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card2"
    Driver      "amdgpu"
    BusID       "PCI:48:0:1"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
        Option     "metamodes" "DisplayPort-0: 1920x1080_60 +0+0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen1"
    Device     "Card1"
    Monitor    "Monitor1"
        Option     "metamodes" "DFP-3: 1920x1080_75 +0+0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen2"
    Device     "Card2"
    Monitor    "Monitor2"
        Option     "metamodes" "HDMI-A-0: 1920x1080_60 +0+0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a Screen setting to each one of your Device sections:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "amdgpu"
    BusID       "PCI:48:0:0"
    Screen      0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card1"
    Driver      "nvidia"
    BusID       "PCI:16:0:0"
    Screen      1
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card2"
    Driver      "amdgpu"
    BusID       "PCI:48:0:1"
    Screen      2
EndSection
```

I have a similar set up, and that is the only noticeable difference I can see.

Comment: Already have done that, does nothing but add redundancy given the screens to devices are noted in the screen section themselves. This is one of those unspoken changes where once Screen 0 in the device section was the norm but now it's not. Either way neither work.

Comment: I missed that you have an nvidia GPU and an AMD gpu the first time. I've seen others be successful in setting this up using prime, but I'm not sure if they were also attempting to set up separate X screens. Here is one such example: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxhardware/comments/he9nhe/amd_and_nvidia_gpus_in_the_same_machine_it_works/

Comment: Prime is basically xrandr style which is brutally destroys performance. The point of a classic X11 XScreen set up is GPU segregation. Any other Wayland/Xrandr style lump the GPU's together in a "weakest sets the bar" situation so your best GPU is crippled by the slowest/weakest. I've run mixed brand in the past fine, ran nVidia, nVidia, AMD triple for years but this one just won't work. Not sure if it's the AMDGPU driver as back in the day I was using the radeon. Even just the AMD alone ignores the XScreens and goes xrandr style.

Comment: I just noticed you said you had a similar setup (my lord how did I not see that?!) May I ask what are you running and which drivers? The last Radeon I had was pre AMDGPU driver...like RIGHT before it but in classic AMD fashion even though the card was new they didn't deem it worthy of the new driver. So this is the first time I've used it which has had me wondering is this a driver quirk?! Sadly it could also be how the board/cpu works with it. The issue is a lot how some VM's ignore XScreens and output as a single "head" no matter what.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice you had the amd nvidia combo in my original answer. I just have two nvidia GPUs that I use to set up multiple X screens across and unfortunately do not have an AMD gpu that I could try out. Does your Xorg.0.log show anything that indicates the amdgpu driver is ignoring X screens?

Comment: No nothing in the log, in fact the log explicitly shows all 3 screens created.

[     7.126] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[     7.126] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[     7.126] (**) |   |-->Device "Card0"
[     7.126] (**) |-->Screen "Screen1" (1)
[     7.126] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor1"
[     7.126] (**) |   |-->Device "Card1"
[     7.126] (**) |-->Screen "Screen2" (2)
[     7.126] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor2"
[     7.126] (**) |   |-->Device "Card2"

Comment: A bit later in the log it kicks out the following - note the "spanning desktop" I suspect that is what is breaking everything but I can't find anything on why it keeps enabling that. [     8.038] (II) AMDGPU(0): Output DisplayPort-0 connected
[     8.038] (II) AMDGPU(0): Output DisplayPort-1 disconnected
[     8.038] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using spanning desktop for initial modes
[     8.038] (II) AMDGPU(0): Output HDMI-A-0 using initial mode 1920x1080 +0+0
[     8.038] (II) AMDGPU(0): Output DisplayPort-0 using initial mode 1920x1080 +1920+0

Comment: On multi nVidia this "Desktop Spanning" is never enabled which again seems like a quirk of the AMD driver. However trying to find docs or even mentions of what X11 Desktop Spanning is much less how to enable/disable/configure yields nothing.

Comment: This is the only thing I've found in relation to what you're trying to set up: https://www.linux.org/threads/dual-dedicated-gpu-each-with-its-own-monitor.37611/

Basically it seems like amdgpu does not play super nice with separate X screens to begin with, and then adding in that you're mixing drivers complicates things further. In general separate X screens just does not get much love since I think it is a pretty niche set up. Which is a shame because I think the separation of workspace can be super helpful in organizing a workflow.

Comment: So driver quirk. Yeah XScreens allowing you to direct work to a specific GPU is super important. Comically I was banned from linux.org just for signing up (my email domain is instaflagged because it's alpha numeric). Thanks for continuing to poke around. I've been sidetracked with garden and home issues. I suppose I'll mark this is unsolvable heh. I'd actually read that post a while ago but it kinda touches on issues I saw last year but no real resolution, just lots of issues. There are a few ways to do what he's doing (local XPRA or multi seat yada) but it's still broken bandaid stuff.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the latest release of KDE5 plasma  stop supporting the X screens as well. I've never had the need to directly work with a specific GPU, but getting so many individual workspaces has always been awesome. Best of luck!

Comment: That's sad to note as KDE as of at least a few months ago was the only full DE that seemed to be working. Albeit with some terrible UI behaviors for multi screens. Good thing I run CTWM but sadly I suspect that machine is a lost cause. The onboard GPU was just a waste of cash.